# Map through Data in React and recieving - TypeError: Object(...)(...) is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm receiving the error TypeError: Object(...)(...) is undefined. When trying to map.

```
drinks  
0   
strDrink    "'57 Chevy with a White License Plate"
strDrinkThumb   "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/qyyvtu1468878544.jpg"
idDrink "14029"
1   
strDrink    "155 Belmont"
strDrinkThumb   "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/yqvvqs1475667388.jpg"
idDrink "15346"
2   
strDrink    "747 Drink"
strDrinkThumb   "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/8ozumt1572901761.jpg"
idDrink "178318"
```

Drinks is an Array of Objects.

Im fetching the data in context

```
 const [cocktails, setCocktails] = useState([]);

  const baseUrl = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/';

  const fetchCocktailList = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}filter.php?c=Cocktail`);
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error fetching data');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetchCocktailList().then((data) => setCocktails(data));
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);
```

and maping like so

```
const DrinkList = ({ drinks, isLoading }) => {
  return (
    <div className='drink-list-wrapper'>
      {isLoading ? (
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
      ) : (
        drinks.map((drink) => <DrinkItem key={drink.idDrink} drink={drink} />)
      )}
    </div>
```

If someone could explain this to me? I've tried making the initial value of cocktails to an empty object first.

```
const DrinkPage = () => {
  const { cocktails } = useContext(DataContext);
  const { isLoading } = useContext(DataContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <DrinkList drinks={cocktails} isLoading={isLoading} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have console.logged data fetched and it says its an object.

Comment: Can you please also show where you use DrinksList?

Comment: I've edited to show where I use it.

Comment: Which component is throwing the error? Could it be `DrinkItem`?

Comment: When I go on the DrinkPage the error throws.

Comment: const { cocktails } = useContext(DataContext); this is what the browser points to.

Comment: I haven't used newer versions of React, but are you supposed to use curly braces around a variable name when you're declaring it? I can't think of a JavaScript reason to do that.

Comment: Oh, NVM, it's a spread operator. Is useContext(DataContext) an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchCocktailList` is returning the data, however the hook is interpreting that it returns a Promise: `fetchCocktailList().then((data) => setCocktails(data));`

My suggestion is to move `fetchCocktailList` inside the hook as it is only being used there; move the logic related to the fetch (state changes) inside the function.

```
const [cocktails, setCocktails] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCocktailList = async () => {
        const baseUrl = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/";

        setLoading(true);

        try {
            const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}filter.php?c=Cocktail`);
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data);

            setCocktails(data);
            setLoading(false);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error fetching data");

            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    fetchCocktailList();
}, []);
```

This however doesn't seem related to the error you get, but it might help to figure it out.
The error might come from the returned `data`, make sure it is returning the array of items and not an object with a property containing the array, for example: `{ drinks: [] }`.

Comment: console.log shows it is returning an object with a property containing arrays. Like this `{ drinks: [] }` How do I overcome this? I have moved the fetch in the hook like you suggested.

Comment: Then simply use that property to set the cocktails state: `setCocktails(data.drinks)`